# FFMpeg: How to merge two audio streams of two videoclips merged as PIP, with the audio starting at a specific timing offset

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm merging two videos using picture-in-picture in FFMPEG. The full resolution background video can be of variable length, the PIP video however is only 10 seconds long. The PIP video needs to appear after exactly 7 seconds. I've managed to merge the videos just fine using the command below.

Now I also need to merge the audio streams. This also works, except the offset used for the video (set by using -itsoffset 7 and enable=between(t, 7, 17) does not apply to the merged audiostream, causing the audio of the PIP video to already start at the beginning of the video, at 00:00 instead of at 00:07 and the audio track is also cut off after 10s (the duration of the PIP track).

My current command is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i "background_vid.mp4" -itsoffset 7 -i "pip_vid.mp4" -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/4:ih/4 [pip]; [0][pip] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable='between(t,7,17)' [v];[0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -profile:v main -level 3.1 -b:v 5000k -ar 44100 -ab 128k -s 1920x1080 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac output.mp4
```

To clarify, the audio of the background vid should start as usual at 00:00. I want the audio of the pip_vid (10s in duration) to be merged with the background_vid audio (variable length) starting at 00:07 seconds, the same time when the PIP video will appear on-screen. After the PIP video disappears, the audiostream from the background video should continue to play.

Is there any way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audio mix filters don't account for starting timestamps, so you have to pad the stream initially with silence.

Use

`ffmpeg -i "background_vid.mp4" -itsoffset 7 -i "pip_vid.mp4" -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/4:ih/4 [pip]; [0][pip] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable='between(t,7,17)' [v];[1:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[pip-a];[0:a][pip-a]amerge[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -profile:v main -level 3.1 -b:v 5000k -ar 44100 -ab 128k -s 1920x1080 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac output.mp4`

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to post the full log in a comment, but it exceeds the character limit. It now gives the following error: 

`[Parsed_amerge_3 @ 00000248e86aee00] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_3 @ 00000248e86aee00] No channel layout for input 2
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000248e903f300] The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_3
Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: I/O error
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!`

Comment: That's an issue with amerge. Use amix instead. Logs are usually uploaded to somewhere like pastebin and then linked here.

Comment: Fantastic, it works. Thank you very much for your help, it's very much appreciated!